# jQuery - tolerance: 'fit' of a droppable does not care about border-setting of droppable

Tags: jquery, border, droppable

I'm developing a little tool and it works so far, but I interfere with the fact that the droppable (with option 'tolerance' set to 'fit') obviously doesn't care about the border of a droppable.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/scraddy/8geEB/20/

Relevant javascript extracted from fiddle:

```
$("#dropzone").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#dropzone p").hide();
        $("#pix img").draggable("disable").hover(function() {
            $(this).css({
                cursor: "default"
            });
        });
    }
});

$("#pix img").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($("#dropzone p").is(":hidden")) {
            $(ui.helper).clone().appendTo($("#dropzone")).resizable({
                handles: 'se',
                maxHeight: 200,
                minHeight: 25,
                aspectRatio: true,
                ghost: true,
                autoHide: true,
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    var ximg = ui.position.left + ui.size.width;
                    var xdrop = $("#dropzone").offset().left + $("#dropzone").width();
                    var yimg = ui.position.top + ui.size.height;
                    var ydrop = $("#dropzone").offset().top + $("#dropzone").height();
                    if (ximg > xdrop || yimg > ydrop) {
                        $(this).position({
                            my: "right bottom",
                            at: "right bottom",
                            of: "#dropzone",
                            offset: ((xdrop - ximg) < 0 ? 0 : -(xdrop - ximg)) + " " + ((ydrop - yimg) < 0 ? 0 : -(ydrop - yimg))
                        });
                    }
                }
            }).parent().draggable({
                disabled: false,
                helper: "original",
                containment: "#dropzone",
                create: function(event, ui) {
                    if ($("#testing").size() === 0) {
                        $("#dropzone div.ui-wrapper").append('<img id="testing" src="http://palmenhandel-witten.de/img/close.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Bild entfernen" />');
                        $("img#testing").click(function() {
                            $("#dropzone p").fadeIn(350);
                            $("#dropzone div.ui-wrapper").resizable('destroy').draggable('destroy');
                            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").fadeOut(350, function() {
                                $(this).remove()
                            });
                            $("#pix img").draggable("enable").hover(function() {
                                $(this).css({
                                    cursor: "move"
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    $("#dropzone div.ui-wrapper").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event) {
                        $("img#testing").toggleClass("over");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
        cursor: "move"
    });
});
```

When you drag an image to the droppable it should only be accepted when it's completely over the droppable and no part of it over the droppable's border. The border belongs to the droppable, of course, but I ask myself if there is maybe a workaround for this?

I thought of manually reposition the draggable after dropping, but this will be cumbersome, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with manually reposition the draggable after adding to the droppable. Here is the edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scraddy/8geEB/27/